# Is there a difference between "ascendants" and "ancestors"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

Without noticing myself, I've mixed the use of "ascendants" and "ancestors" in some documentation I've written.

In an arbitrary hierarchy (of either people or *things*), what would be the most correct term to use, to describe my parent(s) parent(s) parent(s), etc.?

That is, *descendants* would be my children, their children, and so forth. In the exact reverse order, would *ascendants* and *ancestors* be interchangeable, or would one be preferred over the other?

Both [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ascendant) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ascendant) lists ancestor as a synonym of ascendants, though neither precisely defines it in the context of a hierarchy per se.

Comment: Yes they're interchangeable, but *ancestors* is more recent and more widely used and recognised.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question should include your research on the matter -- in this case, for example, dictionaries you consulted and why the result was inadequate. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd Thanks - I've added links to the dictionaries I checked.

Comment: In programming `ascendants` is sometimes used in technical lingo to refer to hierarchically organized "things" which do not (necessarily) represent people. So in programming `ascendants` is used as a more generic concept than `ancestors`. Ex.: categories (and other taxonomies) may have a parent, children, ascendants, descendants. Other than that I perceive them as full synonyms -- and I am aware that ascendants is far less commonplace.

Comment: FWIW, the popular culture usage that tweaked my interest.
"We, the last unbroken remnants,
vow to undo the errors of our ascendants.
To make the Earth whole,
the lost unlost,
at peril of our own birth."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ascendant* does have the meaning you use here, but it is rare, and many may not know that sense of the word, so you should favour *ancestor*.

(The other senses of *ascendant* do also have *descendant* as an antonym too, so if you look up the antonym of *descendant* you may find *ascendant* cited for that reason more than for this rare sense).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is *antecedent vs. ancestor*. I am not sure if *ascendent* connotes the meaning you have in mind, but the two others I suggested would be interchangeable in some contexts. However, in your specific case *ancestor* seems to be a better fit.

Comment: *Ascendant/ascendent* (both spellings are found) can mean what the querent asks about here too. It's just so rare as to be ill-advised.

Comment: From OED: Ascendent/ascendant: One who precedes in genealogical succession; an ancestor; a relative in the ascending line, whether lineal, as father, mother, or collateral, as uncle, great-uncle.